# Updating Python 3.7 to 3.8 on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python-3, update

I recently updated my Raspberry Pi with `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt full-upgrade` to the system. Even if Python 3.8 is out, when I run `python3` in terminal, it shows me version 3.7, instead of 3.8.

Why is this the case?

Comment: Because that is what is available in the default repos. It takes time for a package to go from release to inclusion in the repos, and hence available for install.

Comment: Cool. You can leave an answer if you wish :)

Comment: If you want 3.8 you will have to  compile from source or wait for Bullseye - probably mid 2021, but a Raspberry Pi release is unlikely before end 2021. See https://wiki.debian.org/Python

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Why? Just because it takes a while for distributions to integrate new versions.

Here's what I did to install Python 3.8.5 on my rpi:

```
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential tk-dev libncurses5-dev \
libncursesw5-dev libreadline6-dev libdb5.3-dev libgdbm-dev libsqlite3-dev \
libssl-dev libbz2-dev libexpat1-dev liblzma-dev zlib1g-dev libffi-dev

version=3.8.5

wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/$version/Python-$version.tgz

tar zxf Python-$version.tgz
cd Python-$version
./configure --enable-optimizations
make -j4
sudo make altinstall
```

Installs Python into /usr/local/bin

Comment: You remind me last time I upgraded my jessie python 3.5.3 to 3.7.3. I needed to upgrade because I wanted to learn tensorflow which at that time only supported python 3.7. At that time I had 10 years expereince in Wi95/XT/ .. Win7, and I knew all the batch commands like CD (change directory, make directory, copy/remove files, zip/unzip files etc), so I though I was knowledge enough to do the python 3.7 upgrade. But then I did not know what were tar, zxf, tgz, ... So it took me more than 4 hours (yes 4 hours) to mess up jessie. Fortunately I had a micro SD backup of jessie. My lesson learnt, ..

Comment: Cheers, copy paste friendly galore. Takes about 10min to compile, which is pretty fast and as mentioned it won't override the default Python's symlink or anything, but instead create a completely separate /usr/bin/python3.8 along side whatever is already there. Might get issues later in life when Debian* decides to upgrade finally.

Comment: How do you activate 3.8 once everything compiles? Does the pi need to be rebooted? If I do a `python3 --version` its still 3.7

Answer (score 1):

This is worth sharing, someone made a bash script.

> Ultimate Python installation on a Raspberry Pi & Ubuntu Script

This seems like an interesting site:
https://itheo.tech/ultimate-python-installation-on-a-raspberry-pi-ubuntu-script