# How to guess the date when Python 3.8 will be available on the default repos?

Tags: python, repository

I have to update from Python 3.7 to 3.8, just like in [Updating Python 3.7 to 3.8](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/116118/updating-python-3-7-to-3-8). In my case, it is to run HomeAssistant.

I understood that `apt` cannot find the package in the default repository.

However, I couldn't find how long does it take for the package to be available, so I could know if it is worth waiting. Where could I find this information?

Moreover, if the package is not available yet, wouldn't it be because the stability not optimal yet? Otherwise, what would be the difference between the manual installation and the future repository-base `apt` installation?

Comment: Simple NEVER. The next Debian release will probably have 3.9

Comment: @Milliways but why?

Comment: You'll need to wait for Bullseye to emerge from his stable.

Comment: @Dougie I'm sorry but those comments are 100% cryptic to a noob like me. Could you explain a little bit? TMLI5.

Comment: RaspiOS is based on DebIan. The current RaspiOS version is Buster. The next (in autumn 2021) will be RaspiOS Bullseye (the DebIan versions are named after Toy Story characters). You won't get a python version change except on a DebIan version change - because that's how DebIan likes to do it to remain a stable release. Bullseye is Woody's horse (so I was punning on the word stable as in "unchanging" and "accomodation for equine animals").

Comment: @Dougie the pun makes a lot more sense now :-) You should definitely make this an answer. Anyway, this means that I really have to install python manually. Would you have any opinion about the stability of such an install?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to wait for Bullseye to emerge as the stable version.

RaspiOS is based on DebIan. The current RaspiOS version is Buster. The next (in autumn 2021) will be RaspiOS Bullseye (the DebIan versions are named after Toy Story characters). You won't get a python version change except on a DebIan version change - because that's how DebIan likes to do it to remain a stable release.

Comment: Thanks! So if this is a stability matter, does this mean that Python 3.8 will not be that stable on Buster?

Comment: No it means that DebIan don't want to make changes for a published distro. If you want rapid changes and leading edge versions us Ubuntu.